# Jenkins Blue ocean not opening jobs defined with folder plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using latest Jenkins with Blue Ocean and folder plugin. If I define the job with folder plugin, when click O**pen Blue Ocean** link its not opening the job page.

**Here is my steps.**

1. Create folder name with `Test Foler`
2. Create pipeline job with name `Hello World`

Save the job and try to click the Open Blue Ocean link, it’s not working.

its trying to open this URL

`/jenkins/blue/organizations/jenkins/Test%20Folder/Hello%20World%20Job/`

correct URL is

`/jenkins/blue/organizations/jenkins/Test%20Folder%2FHello%20World%20Job/activity`

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that looks like a bug and the right place to go is [issues.jenkins-ci.org](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org).